# Add a link to an Element with PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I make a PHP script using DOM to auto-resize the images on the fly. The script works but i have a problem when i try to encapsulate a resized image between `<a ...>` and `</a>` (to show the normal size in a lightbox).

Problem is resized images are shown at the end of the $html output, which is not the correct position. What am i doing wrong please ?

Here is my code :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$max_width = 530;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
$img_width = $image->getAttribute('width');
$img_height = $image->getAttribute('height');

if($img_width > $max_width) {
    //Scale
    $scale_factor = $max_width/$img_width;
    $new_height = floor($img_height * $scale_factor);           
    //Set new attributes
    $image->setAttribute('width', $max_width);
    $image->setAttribute('height', $new_height);
    //Add Link
    $Zoom = $dom->createElement('a');
    $Zoom->setAttribute('class', 'zoom');
    $Zoom->setAttribute('href', $src);
    $dom->appendChild($Zoom);
    $Zoom->appendChild($image);
}
}
```

thank for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this with [`replaceChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) instead:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $img_width = $image->getAttribute('width');
    $img_height = $image->getAttribute('height');

    if($img_width > $max_width) {
        //Scale
        $scale_factor = $max_width/$img_width;
        $new_height = floor($img_height * $scale_factor);           
        //Set new attributes
        $image->setAttribute('width', $max_width);
        $image->setAttribute('height', $new_height);
        //Add Link
        $Zoom = $dom->createElement('a');
        $Zoom->setAttribute('class', 'zoom');
        $Zoom->setAttribute('href', $src);

        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($Zoom, $image);
        $Zoom->appendChild($image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works ! I just noticed that I had tried these 2 lines before, but in the wrong order (I was really close). thank you !

Comment: @sun That wouldn't work because `$image` wouldn't have had the right`parentNode` to work from, since you'd appended it to `$Zoom`. Glad to help!